# Are these predicative complements or adverbials?

Tags: adverbs, complements

> As Harry helped himself to a treacle tart, the talk turned to their
> families.
>
> "I'm half-and-half," said Seamus. "Me dad's a Muggle. Mom didn't tell
> him she was a witch 'til after they were married. Bit of a nasty shock
> for him."
>
> The others laughed.
>
> "What about you, Neville?" said Ron.
>
> "Well, my gran brought me up and she's a witch," said Neville, "but
> the family thought I was all-Muggle for ages. My Great Uncle Algie
> kept trying to catch me **off my guard [i]** and force some magic
> **out of me [ii]** -- he pushed me **off the end of Blackpool pier [iii]** once, I nearly drowned -- but nothing happened until I was
> eight. Great Uncle Algie came round for dinner, and he was hanging me
> **out of an upstairs window [iv]** by the ankles when my Great Auntie Enid offered him a meringue and he accidentally let go. But I bounced
> -- all the way down the garden and into the road. They were all really pleased, Gran was crying, she was so happy. And you should have seen
> their faces when I got in here -- they thought I might not be magic
> enough to come, you see. Great Uncle Algie was so pleased he bought me
> my toad."
>
> --- Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

[i] can be called [a depictive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91077/is-this-an-objective-complement-or-adjective-phrase). I guess [iii] could be a resultative. For [ii] and [iii], it’s not that easy. At a glance, they are like resultatives, and yet they seem to be like adverbials with locative or directional meaning. May I be helped understood better?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by an *adverb* or an *adverbial*: is it a sentential function (modifies a clause or verb or adjective) or a semantic class (designates a manner, location, position, direction, &c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making two mistakes here.

The first is supposing that these preposition phrases must be *either* predicative complements *or* adverbials. They are both: complements syntactically and adverbials semantically. The complements these idioms require are supplied by adverbial expressions--which you may regard as functional adjectives, since they are all to some degree attributed to nouns!

The second mistake is supposing that the categories *resultative* and *depictive*  represent ‘real’ entities. They're only handles for naming contrasting semantic roles played by the complements: they help you grasp the difference, but they're neither exhaustive nor constitutive.